# How Perforce command ''P4 changes" work

Tags: perforce, changelist

I am developing an application that is supposed to be integrated with Perforce. In the learning phase of basic Perforce command, I have a question of how 'p4 changes' work. Once a changelist get submitted, say, affecting files at

> 1. '//depot/Web/content/main.css'
> 2. '//depot/Tool/app/init.py'

If we now issue a command:

> 'p4 changes //depot/Web/...'

then the changelist will show in the result. So how Perforce manage this information? Does it break down the paths and store? Or does it do an online substring query?

I saw there is a field "common path" in Perforce database schema, in this case, the value should be:

> '//depot/...'

So in this case, how does Perforce get the information?

Comment: Seems like a good question to me. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each change, the Perforce server records which files were affected by that change.

This is one of many pieces of metadata about the changelist which are recorded in the server's database.

That information is used by commands like 'p4 describe' to find the correct set of files.

The Perforce server contains a sophisticated pattern matching engine which can rapidly search through the database to locate the set of changes which affected a certain set of files, as described by a file pattern.

This is a core operation of the server, so it's highly optimized for this behavior.

Comment: Still unclear: Is the "common path" (a.k.a. "root" in db.change[x]) used by the "p4 changes" command?

Comment: thanks for the input. If the "common path" is used, then for all 'p4 changes' queries with a 'path' parameter whose prefix is the "common path", it has to first of all find all "possible" changelists with that "common path", and iterate thru them to check if any file path affected by that changelist is in the path provided as a parameter. This should bring the performance down significantly. Is this where most of the optimizations happen in this way?

Comment: There are a variety of optimizations, I believe, depending on the details of the arguments given to 'p4 changes'. The optimizations have been extended and adjusted over the years, so if you're worried about the performance of a particular comment, your best bet is to contact Perforce support for assistance in optimizing your query.

Comment: The common path **is** used in the p4 changes command, but mostly for security purposes, not for searching.